# Confusion between 'have been' and 'were'

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple, sentence-choice

Which one is correct or more appropriate?

> 1. Several investigations **have been conducted** on this topic.
> 2. Several investigations **were conducted** on this topic.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Warda! Please try to show your own effort in your questions. You can do this by sharing your own thoughts on the question, by telling what you tried to read about the issue and what have you found out. Example: "I believe sentence 2 is more appropriate because it uses the Simple Past tense, and ..." or "I've found out that when we use the Present Perfect, we usually..."